# Nodejs : TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type number

Tags: node.js

I am just started learning streams, I am trying to write the number to newfile.txt but it throws a error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of
> type string or Buffer. Received type number

The code

```
const {Readable,pipeline} = require('stream');
const {createWriteStream} = require('fs');

async function myfunc(){
    const stream = Readable.from(Array.from({length:20},(x,i)=>i+1));
    pipeline(stream,createWriteStream('./newfile.txt'),(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    })
}

myfunc();
```

Answer (score 2):

`pipeline` expects the first argument to be of type `ReadableStream`. `Readable.from` returns value of type `internal.Readable` (not the required readable stream type), that is why you see the error.

Here is an example of how you would use it (loading file as a readable stream and then pushing it to write stream).

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream');
const { createWriteStream, createReadStream } = require('fs');

async function myfunc() {
    const stream = createReadStream('./oldfile.txt');
    pipeline(stream, createWriteStream('./newfile.txt'), (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

myfunc();
```

If you want to push some string (or an object) into a writable stream using `pipeline` instead of loading contents of some file, you can create readable stream using `Duplex`

```
const { Duplex, pipeline } = require('stream');
const { createWriteStream } = require('fs');

const b = Buffer.from('some text');
const readStream = Duplex();
readStream.push(b);
readStream.push(null);

pipeline(readStream, createWriteStream('./newfile.txt'), (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```